# Conditionally Replace XML Tag Value Using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, csv, xslt-2.0

I am working with XSLT 2.0 (Saxon processor) and trying to transform a xml to another. Here's how the sample input xml looks like

```
<Customer>
    <Name>{{customer_name}}</Name>
    <Transaction>{{customer_transaction}}</Transaction>
    <Id>134</Id>
</Customer>
```

How do I check the value of each xml tag and verify if its a field name for e.g. customer_name or customer_transaction? If it is a field name then I need to look up its value in an external csv file and replace its value.

Here's the xsl template I have programmed so far. Could someone assist me in completing it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fn="fn"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="csv-uri"
               select="'file:///E:/data.csv'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="csv" select="unparsed-text($csv-uri)"/>


    <!-- Identity template : copy all text nodes, elements and attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="fn:getTokens" as="xs:string+">
        <xsl:param name="str" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="concat($str, ',')" regex='(("[^"]*")+|[^,]*),'>
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:sequence select='replace(regex-group(1), "^""|""$|("")""", "$1")'/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:variable name="lines" select="tokenize($csv, '\r\n')" as="xs:string+"/>
    <xsl:variable name="headerColNames" select="fn:getTokens($lines[1])" as="xs:string+"/>

    <xsl:template match="*/text()[starts-with(.,'{{')]">
        <!-- add more code here -->   
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the data.csv has the below data

```
customer_name, customer_transaction
abc, T1
xyz, T2
```

The output xml should look like

```
<Customer>
    <Name>abc</Name>
    <Transaction>T1</Transaction>
    <Id>134</Id>
</Customer>
```

Note that we are concerned only about the first record.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider to "transform" the CSV to XML first and then match and select, here is an XSLT 3 solution doing that (could be converted to XSLT 2 with some more lines of code but Saxon 9.8 runs XSLT 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="csv-uri" as="xs:string">test2017110601.txt</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="field-pattern" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">\{\{.+\}\}</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="repl-pattern" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">^\{\{|\}\}$</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="sep-pattern" as="xs:string">,\s*</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="csv-lines" as="xs:string*" select="unparsed-text-lines($csv-uri)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="col-names" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(head($csv-lines), $sep-pattern)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="csv-doc">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tail($csv-lines)[normalize-space()]" mode="lines"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:key name="fields" match="row/*" use="local-name()"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]" mode="lines">
        <row>
            <xsl:variable name="cols" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(., ',\s*')"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$col-names">
                <xsl:element name="{.}">{let $p := position() return $cols[$p]}</xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and matches(., $field-pattern)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('fields', replace(., $repl-pattern, ''), $csv-doc)[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is an XSLT 2 version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="csv-uri" as="xs:string">test2017110601.txt</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="field-pattern" as="xs:string">\{\{.+\}\}</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="repl-pattern" as="xs:string">^\{\{|\}\}$</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="sep-pattern" as="xs:string">,\s*</xsl:param>

    <xsl:param name="csv-lines" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(unparsed-text($csv-uri), '\r?\n')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="col-names" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize($csv-lines[1], $sep-pattern)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="csv-doc">
        <xsl:for-each select="$csv-lines[position() gt 1][normalize-space()]">
            <row>
                <xsl:variable name="cols" as="xs:string*" select="tokenize(., ',\s*')"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="$col-names">
                    <xsl:element name="{.}">
                        <xsl:variable name="p" as="xs:integer" select="position()"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$cols[$p]"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:key name="fields" match="row/*" use="local-name()"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*) and matches(., $field-pattern)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('fields', replace(., $repl-pattern, ''), $csv-doc)[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```